# What does 'da' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm studying German using Delfin. In the reading book,lesson 8, page 80, there's the following Paragraph:

> Das Kind malt mit einem Buntstift auf die Tischdecke. Alle Tische haben Decken. Einige haben Kaffeeflecken. Die ***da*** bekommt jetzt auch noch rote Striche.

I think it is 'Die da' which means 'The one over there', but not quite sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. *Die/der/das da* or *diese/r/s da* translates to *this one there*. Mostly it is used in spoken language along with pointing to the thing you mean. In purely written language it is not used very often, as you can not transport the "pointing" in written language. Mostly, you'll see something like this:

> Sie zeigte auf die weiße Tischdecke mit den Kaffeeflecken und bemerkte: "Die da bekommt jetzt auch noch rote Striche!"

---

On a side note, you need to make sure not to mix up the following:

> Was will denn die da?
>   Was will die denn da?

The former means: *What does she (the one over there) want?*.
The latter means: *What does she want here/there?*

Comment: And to make matters even more complicated: the first of your last examples can have *both* meanings depending on stress.